# getting the event from variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar

i m studing the jquery calendar from github: https://github.com/themouette/jquery-week-calendar

I pull the data from database by using code behind C#, and stored it at hiddenfield, then javascript read the hiddenfield field value as string.

i will skip how i get the value from database, in this question, i hardcode the events into sampleEvents var.

**Working Javascript:**

```
 var eventData = {
      events: [
{'id':1, 'start': new Date(2015, 3, 27, 12), 'end': new Date(2015, 3, 27, 13, 35),'title':'Lunch with Mike'},
{'id':2, 'start': new Date(2015, 3, 28, 10), 'end': new Date(2015, 3, 28, 14, 45),'title':'Dev Meeting'}
]};
```

**Not Working Javascript:**

```
var sampleEvents = "{'id':1, 'start': new Date(2015, 3, 27, 12), 'end': new Date(2015, 3, 27, 13, 35),'title':'Lunch with Mike'},{'id':2, 'start': new Date(2015, 3, 28, 10), 'end': new Date(2015, 3, 28, 14, 45),'title':'Dev Meeting'}";

 var eventData = {
      events: [
         sampleEvents
]};
```

Error message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getTime' of undefined
```

**Not Working Javascript 2:**

```
var sampleEvents = "[{'id': 1,'start': new Date(2015, 3, 27, 12),'end': new Date(2015, 3, 27, 13, 35),'title': 'Lunch with Mike'},{'id': 2,'start': new Date(2015, 3, 28, 10),'end': new Date(2015, 3, 28, 14, 45),'title': 'Dev Meeting'}]";

var array = JSON.parse(sampleEvents);

var eventData = {
       events: 
           sampleEvents
};
```

Error Messsage:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '
```

Can anyone tell me, what did i missed?

Comment: because `sampleEvents` is a string not an array .. try `events: JSON.parse( sampleEvents)`

Comment: Or send it as an array

Comment: Remove the quotes(`"`) from sampleEvents and it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your created `sampleEvents` is string not array.

`event` is accepting `array` not a `string`.

**To use array try this:**

```
var sampleEvents = [
    {
        'id':1, 
        'start': new Date(2015, 3, 27, 12), 
        'end': new Date(2015, 3, 27, 13, 35),
        'title':'Lunch with Mike'
    },
    {
        'id':2, 
        'start': new Date(2015, 3, 28, 10), 
        'end': new Date(2015, 3, 28, 14, 45),
        'title':'Dev Meeting'
    }
];
```

**To Use String try this:**

```
var sampleEvents = '['+
    '{"id":1, "start": "'+new Date(2015, 3, 27, 12)+'", "end": "'+new Date(2015, 3, 27, 13, 35)+'","title":"Lunch with Mike"},'+
    '{"id":2, "start": "'+new Date(2015, 3, 28, 10)+'", "end": "'+new Date(2015, 3, 28, 14, 45)+'","title":"Dev Meeting"}'+
    ']';

var sampleEventsArray = JSON.parse(sampleEvents);
```

Comment: thank you. your example is working. but i still want to try it by using string, so i use JSON.parse to convert from string to array, and it's still cannot. kindly see the updated question

Comment: sorry for late reply, im facing some issue transferring the string from c# to javascript, but it's all solved now. and ur code works great!  thanks!

Comment: Can I help with this issue ?